# Return a new React Component on iteration

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I already looked for this problem and found that the most common issue is that people are not returning anything, however, I don't see any problem in my code and don't understand why is not working. Can you please give me a hand?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Book from './Book'

class BookShelf extends Component {
    returnBookComponent(array) {
        return array.map((item) => {
            return (
                <li>
                    <Book
                        title={item.title}
                        authors={item.authors}
                        image={item.imageLinks.thumbnail}
                    />
                </li>
            )
        })
    }

    render () {
        const currentlyReading = this.props.currentlyReading
        return (
            <div className="bookshelf">
                <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{this.props.title}</h2>
                <div className="bookshelf-books">
                    <ol className="books-grid">
                        {this.returnBookComponent(currentlyReading)}
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default BookShelf
```

I already checked [this documentation from React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component)

EDIT: If I add a console.log after this line:
`return array.map((item) => {` it never gets executed. Someone array.map is not iterating the array even if this has 2 elements. I if send `array` to the console then it prints the 2 elements but somehow I *can't* run any Array-like functions on this object. `typeof array` throws `Array`, `array.length` shows 0 when I can confirm in Dev Tools that it has 2 elements. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you show your Array

Comment: did you check whether your function is running or not?

Comment: post all the logs you tried

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the `key`, and open the dev console !

```
returnBookComponent = array => {
    return array.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <li key={index}>
                <Book
                    title={item.title}
                    authors={item.authors}
                    image={item.imageLinks.thumbnail}
                />
            </li>
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: Looking at the React tab in dev tools the <ol> is empty.

Comment: I think `currentlyReading` is empty

Comment: @Rcart Just wanna make sure did you change `returnBookComponent` into an arrow function? like @N.Safi did above?

Comment: It has 2 elements and is passed correctly from the parent.

Comment: @Abdullah, yes I did it and is the same.

Comment: This is the status of the props in Dev Tools:

Props
currentlyReading:
Array[2]
title:
"Currently Reading"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `returnBookComponent` handler function here, rather your component should look like

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Book from './Book'

    class BookShelf extends Component {

        render () {
            const currentBook = this.props.currentlyReading.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <li>
                        <Book
                            title={item.title}
                            authors={item.authors}
                            image={item.imageLinks.thumbnail}
                        />
                    </li>
                )
            });

            return (
                <div className="bookshelf">
                    <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{this.props.title}</h2>
                    <div className="bookshelf-books">
                        <ol className="books-grid">
                            {this.returnBookComponent(currentlyReading)}
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>

            )
        }
    }

    export default BookShelf
```

This should work.

Comment: This is the same thing

Comment: Yes but it's not the question

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is kind of curios to me but I was able to fix the problem.

I have a parent component that is resolving a fetch and once is resolved, it updates the state of currentlyReading. In this parent component render's function I'm passing currentlyReading to this BookShelf component *without checking the promise*.

I had this:

```
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <MainPage
                    currentlyReading={this.state.currentlyReading}
                    wantToRead={this.state.wantToRead}
                    read={this.state.read}
                />
        )}/>
```

And the result of `console.log(this.state.currentlyReading)` was

```
⯈[]
```

of type `Array` with 2 elements.

Now, after checking that the promise was resolved

```
     {this.state.mounted &&
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <MainPage
                    currentlyReading={this.state.currentlyReading}
                    wantToRead={this.state.wantToRead}
                    read={this.state.read}
                />
          )}/> 
     }
```

this is the output of `console.log(this.state.currentlyReading)`

```
⯈(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

So, may I ask you why the heck `⯈[ ]` is a valid Javascript array, with 2 elements and length of `0`?

I'm new to javascript but this results to be kinda crazy.